# Fade in box highlight in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want a fade in (with either timer or keystroke) highlight for a text. Here is the MWE that I was able to do.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\myhl[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[draw=black!40, fill=black!8, anchor=base, rounded corners, inner sep=5pt](char) {{#1}};}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\begin{itemize}
\item Dummy text
\item Again dummy text. \only<1>{Text to be highlighted} \only<2>{\myhl{Text to be highlighted}}
\item Dummy text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a fading effect between the two slides, you can use `\transfade<2>` (you need to a pdf viewer that supports such transitions, e.g. adobe reader in presentation mode).

In addition you can use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library to prevent the jumping of the text in between slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\newcommand<>\myhl[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[alt=#2{fill=black!8,draw=black!40}{fill=bg,draw=bg}, anchor=base, rounded corners, inner sep=5pt](char) {{#1}};%
    }%
}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\transfade<2>

\begin{itemize}
\item Dummy text
\item Again dummy text. \myhl<2>{Text to be highlighted}
\item Dummy text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

another version with less padding inside the gray box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\newcommand<>\myhl[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[alt=#2{fill=black!8,draw=black!40}{fill=bg,draw=bg}, anchor=base, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt](char) {{#1}};%
    }%
}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\transfade<2>

\begin{itemize}
\item Dummy text
\item Again dummy text.\myhl<2>{Text to be highlighted}
\item Dummy text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent and more than enough what I needed. I was wondering if the space between ‘Again dummy text’ and ‘Text to be highlighted’ can be reduced to normal spacing.

Comment: @Mithun There are several possibilities to reduce this space. Should the padding inside the gray box be reduced or should it be moved left where it might overlay the full stop?

Comment: Padding inside the gray box can be reduced such that it will not be overlapped with the full stop even though the text is moved left.

Comment: Because, if needed, I want to use this effect in a tabular environment.

Comment: @Mithun Can you have a look at my edited answer?

Comment: I am so sorry for not using the common senses. When I get free help, my general tendencies are to ask more :) Anyway can you put this edits at the end? The previous 5pt inner separation might be better for someone else.

Comment: @Mithun Don't worry about asking :) I now show both versions